# If A is a nxn singular matrix, then it has a singular value = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

This is a question on a testexam.

But am I correct in assuming that a singular matrix has det = 0, which gives it an eigenvalue of 0 and that gives it a singular value of 0?

Comment: How does a zero eigenvalue imply a zero singular value? If you explain this, then you are okay.

Comment: I thought that singular values were the squareroot of the A(transpose)A. And I thought that At and A have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and your argument is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is singular if and only if there is a non-zero vector $v$ such that $A.v=0$. But then $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @JohnD If $A.v=0$, then $(A^*A).v=0$, and therefore $0$ is a singular value of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a square matrix, then $ \lambda $ is a singular value of $A$ , then there is an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $A^*A$ such that $\lambda= \mu^{1/2}$.

If $A$ is singular, then $A^*A$ is singular.... Conclusion ?